# ngAnimate 1.2.0rc1 - Object #<Object> has no method '$$postDigest'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just set up my angularjs env using all ~1.2 libs of angular

- angular v1.2.0rc1
- angular-animate v1.2.0-rc.2
- angular-route v1.2.0-rc.2

Setup:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ngLocale', 'ngAnimate'])
```

And I am seeing this error once I include ngAnimate into my app module

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '$$postDigest'
at Object.angular.module.config.$provide.decorator.enter 

angular-animate/angular-animate.js:292:22
```

And the Object # is in reference to $rootScope.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that angular v1.2.0rc1 was the issue; for some reason my bower configuration wasn't properly updating angulars lib.

OLD:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2",
    "angular-route": "~1.2",
    "angular-route": "~1.2",
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "es5-shim": "~2.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.2"
  }
}
```

NEW:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-route": "1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.0-rc.2",
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "es5-shim": "~2.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.0-rc.2"
  }
}
```

Cheers!